# How to pass the value from one form to another one?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

I have a MainForm and AnotherForm. AnotherForm is accessed via MainForm's menuItem.

AnotherForm has listView. When user clicks on an item it I want to get the string element and pass it to MainForm's textbox, so the element shows there and AnotherForm is closed. So far AnotherForm closes but nothing shows in the textbox in MainForm. Any suggestions?

```
private void listView1_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = listView1.SelectedItem[0].ToString();
    MainForm mainF = new MainForm(input);// called the constructor
    this.Close(); //close this form and pass the input to MainForm
    mainF.inputTextBox.Text = input;
    mainF.loadThis(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an instance of `MainForm` already, and that's what creates an instance of `AnotherForm`.

Inside the event you posted, you're actually creating an entirely new instance of `MainForm`, never showing it, and then it's destroyed anyway when `AnotherForm` closes.

The reason you see nothing in the text box is because you're looking at the original instance of `MainForm`, which you haven't actually changed.

One quickie way of fixing this would be passing a reference to the original `MainForm` into `AnotherForm`:

```
public class AnotherForm
{
    private MainForm mainF;

    public AnotherForm(MainForm mainF)
    {
        this.mainF = mainF;
    }

    ...
    ...

    private void listView1_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        mainF.inputTextBox.Text = input;
        ...
    }
}
```

Note: Instead of having `AnotherForm` aware of `MainForm`, you might want to switch it around and create a public property in `AnotherForm` like this:

```
public class AnotherForm
{
    public InputValue { get; private set; }

    private void listView1_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        InputValue = input;
        ...
    }
}
```

Which you can then access from `MainForm` when the other form is closed:

```
private void SomeMethodInMainForm()
{
    var newAnotherForm = new AnotherForm();

    newAnotherForm.ShowDialog();

    var inputValueFromAnotherForm = newAnotherForm.InputValue;

    // do something with the input value from "AnotherForm"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `MainForm` has already been created you cannot just create another one in order to access it and set properties.  You've created two separate `MainForm`s (though the 2nd one is hidden because you never showed it).

It sounds like what you want to do is a modal dialog pattern.  Your MainForm is the main window in your application.  You want to have a 2nd form pop up when you click on a menu link.  This is called a dialog.  Then when you close that dialog you want your `MainForm` to retrieve a value as a returned result of the dialog.

In your MainForm the event handler which handles the menu item click should look something like this:

```
private void pickSomethingMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var picker = new PickerDialog())
    {
        if (picker.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            LoadSomething(picker.SomethingPicked);
        }
    }
}
```

Then the following code would be inside your dialog form:

```
public string SomethingPicked { get; private set; }

private void somethingListView_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomethingPicked = somethingListView.SelectedItem[0].ToString();
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

Notice how I named all of the objects with meaningful names.  Well, except for "Something".  It was impossible to tell from your code what you were actually using the dialog to pick.  You should **always** use meaningful names for your objects and variables.  Your code is almost completely nonsensical.

And you should almost never make a control on a Form public like you have with your `inputTextBox`.  You should always expose values you want to share as public properties.

Answer (score 0):

On this presented solution, you could do five main things in order to achieve what you want to do, namely:

```
 1) Declare a global object for AnotherForm in MainForm
 2) Initiate a FromClosing event handler for AnotherForm in MainForm
 3) Make a public property or field in AnotherForm
 4) Before closing in AnotherForm you save it the public property mentioned above
 5) In the MainForm get the public property from AnotherForm
```

Here is the code:

**MainForm**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    AnotherForm anotherForm; // Declare a global object for AnotherForm

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void showToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        anotherForm = new AnotherForm(); // when Menu Item is clicked instantiate the Form
        anotherForm.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(anotherForm_FormClosing); // Add a FormClosing event Handler
        anotherForm.ShowDialog();
    }

    void anotherForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        inputTextBox.Text = anotherForm.listViewValue; // get the Value from public property in AnotherForm
    }
}
```

**AnotherForm**

```
 void listView1_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    listViewValue = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text; // Get the listViewItem value and save to public property
    this.Close(); // Close
 }

 public String listViewValue { get; set; } // public property to store the ListView value
```

One thing to note here in comparison to your code I didn't use `ToString()` in `ListView.SelectedItems`:

```
listView1.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
```

But instead use the `Text` Property:

```
listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
```